# ¿Equivalente en Query Builder a esta Consulta SQL?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder, laravel-8

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql:

```
$sql="select sc.nombre,sc.descripcion,c.nombre AS 'categoria',sc.fecha_registro,sc.hora_registro,sc.estado,sc.hash from sub_categorias AS sc INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON c.idCategoria=sc.idCategoriaFK WHERE sc.estado='A'";
```

y queria saber cual seria el equivalente en **Query Builder** de laravel 8.

por ejemplo para este sql: `select * from persona`, el equivalente en Query Builder seria : `Persona::all()`

Datos adicionales: los **modelos** que estructure en Migraciones son: Categoria y SubCategoria, es el tipico 1 a *

Comment: Es como dice BetaM muestranos que relaciones tienes en tus modelos para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontre la Respuesta, el equivalente seria lo siguiente:

```
SubCategoria::
 join('categorias', 'categorias.idCategoria', '=', 'sub_categorias.idCategoriaFK')
 ->select('sub_categorias.nombre', 'sub_categorias.descripcion', "categorias.nombre AS 'categoria'", 'sub_categorias.fecha_registro', 'sub_categorias.hora_registro', 'sub_categorias.estado', 'sub_categorias.hash')
 ->where('sub_categorias.estado', '=', 'A')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría mucho le des una revisada a [las relaciones en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction), te harán la vida mas simple al momento de construir esta clase de consultas.

Entonces si estamos en una relación de uno a muchos, deberás tener 2 modelos creados:

- Categoria
- Subcategoria

Dentro del modelo `Categoria` vas a componer la siguiente estructura:

```
class Categoria extends Model 
{
    public function subcategorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategoria::class)
                    ->select(['nombre', 'descripcion', 
                                'fecha_registro', 'hora_registro', 
                                'estado', 'hash', 
                                'idCategoriaFK']);
    }

    public function scopeSeleccionaValores($query)
    {
        $query->select(['idCategoria', 'nombre']);
    }
}
```

- El primer método nos sirve para declarar la relación que existirá entre ambos modelos y opcionalmente le podemos encadenar el método `select` para solamente tomar valores de columnas específicas de la entidad `Subcategoria`.
- El segundo método nos sirve para establecer un `select` personalizado de la entidad `Categoria` a través de los denominados [`query scopes locales`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Por otro lado en el modelo `Subcategoria` deberás tener algo como esto:

```
class Subcategoria extends Model 
{
    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
    }
}
```

- Donde al momento solo tenemos un método con el cual completamos la relación.

Finalmente la consulta:

```
$query = Categoria::seleccionaValores()->has('subcategorias')
                                                ->with(['subcategorias' => function($query) {
                                                    $query->whereEstado('A');
                                                }])->get();
```

- Invocamos al *query scope local* que nos hace un `select` personalizado
- Usamos el método [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para solamente traer categorias que tengan al menos una subcategoria asociada (*esto nos ayuda a lidiar con el tema del `INNER JOIN`*)
- Procedemos a hacer [*una carga ambiciosa de las relaciones*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- Considerando que tienes un [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) que nos filtrará por el estado de las subcategorias, entonces debemos pasar una función dentro del método `with()` como valor del array asociativo

Como puntos extra, **considera revisar esto**:

- Tus tablas no siguen las [convenciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) en sus nombres y sus llaves primarias como así las foráneas, dado eso deberás agregar propiedades extra a las clases
- Dado que existe el punto anterior, entonces deberás agregar argumentos extra a tus 2 relaciones declaradas (*esto ya te lo dejo a ti*), [revisa aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) la documentación es muy didáctica e indica donde agregar la llave primaria y la llave foránea